# Middleware throws error "Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL"

Tags: next.js, middleware

I have a middleware in my next app so that it converts all urls (except API routes) to lower case.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const Middleware = (req) => {
  const {
    pathname,
    search,
    origin
  } = req.nextUrl;
  if (pathname.startsWith('/api') || pathname === pathname.toLowerCase())
    return NextResponse.next();

  return NextResponse.redirect(
    `${origin + pathname.toLowerCase() + search}`
  );
};

export default Middleware;
```

It works for what I expect, but the problem is that in all the pages of my application I receive an error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL

This error doesn't seem to affect my application but I would like to know why it is there and how to remove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because of an `Invariant Violation` error that happens when attempting to hard navigate to the same URL after the user has already navigated there.

To solve this issue, you can create a config object and set the matcher property to an array of regular expressions that matches all request paths except for the ones starting with:

- api (API routes)
- _next/static (static files)
- _next/image (image optimization files)
- favicon.ico (favicon file)

To implement this solution, add the following code to your project:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
}
```

Code snippet found in [Next.js Middlewares documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matcher).

The final code will look like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
    '/',
  ],
};

const Middleware = (req) => {
  const {
    pathname,
    search,
    origin
  } = req.nextUrl;
  if (pathname === pathname.toLowerCase())
    return NextResponse.next();

  return NextResponse.redirect(
    `${origin + pathname.toLowerCase() + search}`
  );
};

export default Middleware;
```